# Dispatching web service caller with Response object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I need to dispatch a web service caller to a new page using Response object:

```
@Path("controller")
@Stateless
public class ControllerEJB {
HttpSession session;
User user;
String url;

@POST
public Response registerUser(
        @QueryParam("fornamn") String fornamn, 
        @QueryParam("efternamn") String efternamn,
        @QueryParam("epost") String epost,
        @QueryParam("epost2") String epost2,
        @QueryParam("password") String password,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request
){
    session = request.getSession();
    if(user == null)
        user = new User();
    user.setEmail(epost);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setFornamn(fornamn);
    user.setEfternamn(efternamn);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    return Response.status(200)...... // e.g. url is a .jsp
}
```

What method should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS is designed to build REST services.
REST services should return data, generally serialized using XML or JSON.
I wouldn't recommend to forward JAX-RS requests to a view layer such as JSP or JSF.

That said, i'm not sure you can forward the same way RequestDispatcher.forward(req, res) does.
But you can send a redirection using the following:

```
return Response.seeOther(new URI("/path/to/your/resource")).build();
```

But as the documenation says, this should be used in a POST/redirect/GET pattern: you may redirect a POST request to another REST resource using the GET method.

But again, redirecting REST resource to a JSP page is an awkward design.